# There is some general meaning of angle in geometry?

Tags: geometry, analysis, reference-request, terminology

The other day I discovered the concept of [hyperbolic angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_angle) to denote angles in hyperbolic geometry, as the half of the area between the hyperbola defined by $x^2-y^2=1$ and the $x$-axis.

To be honest I dont know very much about the general concept of geometry in mathematics, so I cant grasp the meaning of the above, if it have some intuitive meaning more than an analogy to the angle and the circle $x^2+y^2=1$.

Where I can understand something is in the realm of analysis or linear algebra.

**My questions:**

1. There is a general concept of angle in mathematics? Not only applicable to euclidean-geometries if not to any other kind of geometries.
2. If so, it can be defined in analytical terms?
3. There is a good reference about this topic understandable to someone with (some) background on analysis or linear algebra?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a general notion of angle via different geometries, per se. http://blog.mathteachersresource.com/?p=670, Maybe these will be of use to you for your Hyperbolic geometry.

Comment: @smokeypeat I understand the notion of angle in euclidean spaces, via inner products, also in submanifolds. But because I saw the definition of hyperbolic angle I guess that it is possible (maybe) a generalized notion of angle. This is the reason for the question.

Comment: This might be helpful as well. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/228487

Comment: @smokeypeat I didnt see before your last comment. It is very interesting to think about an angle defined by the cross of two rays. Probably from this notion it can be developed a general definition of angle for arbitrary geometries.

Comment: You can discuss angles in a general way without assuming Euclidean geometry.  You axiomatize geometry along the lines of Euclid but without the parallel postulate.  This is sometimes called 'neutral' geometry as it generalizes Euclidean and hyperbolic geometry. A good source for this approach is John Lee's [Axiomatic Geometry](https://www.amazon.com/Axiomatic-Geometry-Applied-Undergraduate-Texts/dp/0821884786).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two answers to your question.

1. Euclidean and hyperbolic geometry are instances of **Riemannian geometry**. I am not sure you have enough background to understand what this means but if you have taken vector calculus, you know about (regular) surfaces in 3-d space. At every point $p$ on such a surface $S$ there is a tangent plane $T_pS$ which is a certain 2-dimensional linear subspace passing through $p$. Vectors in $T_pS$ are called **tangent vectors** to $S$ at $p$. Given two nonzero vectors $u, v\in T_pS$ one defines the angle between $u, v$ as the ordinary Euclidean vector. One also has the notion of the dot product  $u\cdot v$.

Riemannian geometry generalizes this picture to "higher dimensions" with surfaces replaced by higher-dimensional objects called **manifolds**. A **Riemannian metric** on a manifold $M$ is a choice of an inner product ("dot product") for vectors $u, v\in T_pM$. Given this, one defines the angle between (nonzero)  vectors $u, v\in T_pM$ as 
$$
arccos\left(\frac{u\cdot v}{|u| ~|v|}\right)
$$
Vectors $u, v$ as above appear as velocity vectors for curves $\alpha, \beta$ in $M$ starting at $p$. Hence, one defines the angle between such curves (at $p$).

My favorite reference is:

M. Do Carmo, [Riemannian Geometry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0817634908).

2. The concept of Riemannian metrics (manifolds) has further generalization, called **metric spaces**. Under some conditions on metric spaces, one can define angles between (geodesic) curves in such spaces. However, this definition is likely to be beyond your level of comfort.

See for instance

D.Burago, S.Ivanov, [A Course in Metric Geometry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821821296).

Comment: I know about submanifolds in $\Bbb R^n$. You mean that hyperbolic geometry behaves locally as standard euclidean geometry after using an atlas? Or more generally, maybe every geometry can be represented locally as an euclidean geometry and, in this setup, define angle as we do in euclidean geometry?

Comment: @Masacroso: No, this is not what I mean.

Comment: @Masacroso: I suggest you take a look in the wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold